# Regex for hex with spaces

Tags: php, regex, hex

Im trying to figure out why this regex doesn't match this line, but i have no more ideas.

```
(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s\s)+
53  65  72  76  65  72  3a  20  41  70  61  63  68  65  00  45
```

but this doesn't catch all the hex bytes ...

**UPD:** i need to catch every bite into preg_match $results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That regex **does** match that line, assuming that the line you've pasted into your question is exactly the line you're matching against:

```
<?php
$hex = "53  65  72  76  65  72  3a  20  41  70  61  63  68  65  00  45  ";

preg_match('/(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s\s)+/', $hex, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(64) "53  65  72  76  65  72  3a  20  41  70  61  63  68  65  00  45  "
  [1]=>
  string(2) "45"
}
```

Most likely what you're trying to do is to get an array of the individual hex bytes, though, so if you're using code similar to the above with that regex, then you're doing it wrong.  It should be something like this, instead:

```
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})\s{2}/', $hex, $matches);
// $matches[1] will be your array of hex bytes
```

Comment: @Fedcomp If you just want to get an array of them, you could use `explode('  ', $hex)` (two spaces as the delimiter)

Comment: @Umbrella: That method doesn't actually match the desired pattern, and would work erroneously for inputs like `"!  ?  ^  $"`.  It would also leave you with a `NULL` array element at the end (due to the trailing spaces), even with the test input.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know those are two spaces and not a tab? Try this regex:

```
/^(?:([a-f0-9]{2})\s*)+$/i
```

Note that I've narrowed it down to only match hex, not base-36. Also, it's possible your regex wasn't matching because it was looking for a space at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

There are only few reasons reasons, why this should not match your input. Please check if the line ends in two spaces and if there are really two white space characters in between each number. Also check if your input does contains character code 160 (unbreakable space), because to my knowledge PCRE does not recognize this as \s.